# How to know the job I am seeking to is for my own company?

Tags: job-search

I work with X and Z Software, divided in 10 specified detailed tasks. However, I found on the Internet a good job post with good salary with Y software that we are starting to use actually along those 10 similar tasks

**My question how do I know that this post is not posted by my company?** What make me suspicious the terms(words) is used in those tasks and they are really specific tasked that I am actually working with them ALL. This software y is similar to x thats why I am seek to seek this new job

Comment: Well... who posted that offer? In what page did you see it?

Comment: Is there relevant context to this question, i.e. why would you suspect your company is keeping their hiring secret?

Comment: @darkcygnus online local job searching engine similar to linked in .. they company was confidential

Comment: @ben mz well i dont know actually but they have this habit that they dont share info about hiring new.people we just know next day a new employe is arriving ..

Answer (score 2):

One easy way I've done for this is just copy/pasting some of the job descriptions into Google. You can specifically put them in `"` too in order to do a strict Google search.

You can also check your own careers page and look there. This can do a few things:

1. If you see a posting similar to the job you think *this* one is describing you can compare
2. You can also see the format your company posts jobs in and identify how close this posting is to those
3. If you saw this on a different job board, take an existing posting from your company page and look for *that* job there to see if your company actually uses that board

Answer (score 2):

**Usually, companies publish offers internally and on their webpage.**

These are shared to allow existing employees to apply for a dream job within the company. Also there are jobs listed in  various referral programs (recommend a friend for this job).

**Maybe your company has such career site, which you can search for the offer and compare if it matches what you found online.**

Comment: OP stated the company has no such policy

Comment: @Grandmaster: Where?

Comment: "well i dont know actually but they have this habit that they dont share info about hiring new.people "

Comment: I understand this as *actual process of hiring* is not shared, not the offers themselves.

Comment: If the jobs are available internally for OP to check, OP wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: @Grandmaster Stack Overflow is filled with questions that could be answered with a simple Google search, or sometimes by just reading the error message they're shown. Not everyone starts by looking where we'd expect them to.

Comment: To the user who raised Low Quality Post flag, what's wrong with this answer? Even the OP's company never posts job offers on their internal web site, this answer is still useful for those who might be able to find  job offers on their internal sites. On Stack Exchange sites, we provide answers not for a specific user, we help everybody who has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there usually is some contact information to the recruiter in such an anonymous advert.

I would start by emailing/calling the recruiter and ask straight out if it is for your company as you were considering applying but for undisclosed reasons want to avoid that company.

Either they answer you or not. Either way, no harm done as you do not have to disclose your identity.